# Interacting with SharePoint list versioning, and C#

Tags: c#, list, sharepoint-2010, version, versioning

I am wondering if there is any way for me to get list versioning data from sharepoint by using C#? I want to make a custom list history, and only need certain data from my list versioning. I have managed to work with list data programatically, and I am thinking there might be a similar way to do it with the versioning data. Does anyone know?

I am using Sharepoint 2010, and Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks :)

Comment: wht u mean by versioning plz explain??

Comment: In SharePoint there is an "out of the" box option for keeping track of your list history. I was wondering if there is any way to access it programatically :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SPListItem.Versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.versions.aspx)